# Get path with PHP for show ErrorDocument styles

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, path, errordocument

I'm using XAMPP with Apache 2.4.18 and PHP 5.5.35.

I have an `.htaccess` for every client's division folder (as I explained [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100407/apache-errordocument-based-on-folder)), where is this code:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /clientName/workDivision1/errors/404.php
```

Same for *workDivision2* and *workDivision3*.

The problem comes when I try to set a path for the styles and scripts.
If I do something like this in the "404.php" file

```
<link href="css/general.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

works fine if the error was triggered from

```
clientName.domain/workDivision1
```

but if it's triggered from

```
clientName.domain/workDivision1/folder/index.php
```

then the styles' path isn't correct anymore.

Is there anyway to solve that with PHP? Anything that isn't insecure?
I'm trying to avoid putting a specific/fixed/defined URL in those links.

---

`dirname(__FILE__)` didn't worked for me because doing this:

```
<link href="<? echo dirname(__FILE__); ?>/css/general.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

creates this:

```
<link href="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/clientName/workDivision1/errors/css/general.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

what in the client becomes:

```
http://(MY LOCAL IP)/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/clientName/workDivision1/css/general.css
```

so it can't found the file.